# How to get the total release number of github projects using api

Tags: github, github-api

I tried to using the api

> https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/releases

to get, but can not get any information.

Could someone help me?

Comment: That's correct, it has no releases: https://github.com/mudge/blankable/releases. What did you expect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, i used wrong example, and i have already edited my question, thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, what the Releases page of github shows is in fact a list of tags. If the author creates an actual release by clicking on the "Add release notes" link, then it will create a true release, listed by the releases API. See for example https://api.github.com/repos/google/guava/releases / https://github.com/google/guava/releases

Comment: @JBNizet I see, then if I wish to get the release numbers of the project, how should I do by using api? Thanks

Comment: By getting the tags.

Comment: @JBNizet but tags return commits?

Comment: https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/tags: that's what it returns. It contains the tag names, which is what you want, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @JBNizet I see, let me try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `curl` command (or any other command-line tool), make sure you're passing the right Authorization token. E.g.

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: token TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repo/releases
```

See: [GitHub API v3 | GitHub Developer Guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/) & [List releases for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graphql API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to get directly the total number of tags :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "mojombo", name: "grit") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", first: 0) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22mojombo%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22grit%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Ftags%2F%22%2C%20first%3A%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)